# Android: Button onClick reacts after 3 seconds

Tags: java, android

I am writing a small app for a Project at my UAC and I have troubles with displaying a ProgressDialog after a onClick event.

Basically when onClick is called in my activity I start an AsyncTask and in the onPreExecute I start the progressDialog and in onPostExecute I dismiss it again.

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = null;
            try {
                ParsedElement x = new ParsedElement(v.getContext());
                Object[] params = new Object[2];
                params[0] = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                params[1] = v;
                recipes = (ArrayList<Recipe>) x.execute(params).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Intent switchToDisplayPage = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, UIGenerator.class);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putParcelableArrayList("recipes", recipes);
            switchToDisplayPage.putExtras(params);
            startActivity(switchToDisplayPage);
        }
    });
```

The problem that I have is when clicking the button "nothing" happens for approx 3 seconds. I already watched the Android Monitor and found out that the CPU usage is maximum 40% when clicking the button.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context v;

public ParsedElement(Context v) {
    this.v = v;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(v);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Recipes are loading...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.show();

}


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {


    String searchString = (String) params[0];
    View v = (View) params[1];

    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ArrayList<URL> single = new ArrayList<>();
        single.add(new URL(Constants.baseSearchURL + searchString));
        Document mainDocument = (Downloaders.getDocumentFromURL(single)).get(0);
        Elements mainElements = mainDocument.select("div.img_wrap img[src]");
        ArrayList<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            urls.add(new URL(Constants.baseSearchURL + searchString +
                    Constants.pageString + Integer.toString(i)));
        }

        ArrayList<Document> tempDocument = Downloaders.getDocumentFromURL(urls);

        for (Document docu : tempDocument) {
            Elements tempElement = docu.select("div.img_wrap img[src]");
            for (Element a : tempElement) {
                mainElements.add(a);
            }
        }

        for (Element link : mainElements) {
            recipes.add(new Recipe(link.attr("title"), link.attr("abs:src")));
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return recipes;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object aVoid) {

    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

In this case the ProgressDialog does not show up. I read a lot of threads which basically stated that "I am doing too much in my main thread" obviously in my case I am not doing anything heavy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. 
It was in this line:

```
recipes = (ArrayList<Recipe>) x.execute(params).get();
```

Although I started an AsyncTask the Main Thread was waiting for the return value of the Task. Thats the reason the Main Thread was blocked.

Instead of returning the value to the activity I just executed the task and moved on in doInBackground.

Hope this helps somebody